# Jquery Action after Checkbox

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

**Here is my JQuery :**

What i have is

While i click the chekcbox,

It will show the alert and it willsend the value $name to the b.php file and it will show the values that is thrown by the b.php in the div #stage in the source file.

But what the issue is, It is showing the result, but it is not showing the values that is returned by the b.php file. What is the mistake i am doing ?

```
<form id="myform">
    <input type="checkbox" name="check1" value="check1" onClick="cbChanged(this);" />
    <input type="checkbox" name="check2" value="check2" onClick="cbChanged(this);" />
</form>
<script>
cbChanged = function(checkboxElem) {
  if (checkboxElem.checked) {
     var name=$("#txt").val();   
       $.post("b.php",
             {name: name}).done(function(data){
              $('#stage').html(data);
               }
          );
    alert("That box was checked.");
  } else {
    alert("That box was unchecked.");
  }
}
</script>
<div id='stage'></div>
```

Here is the code of 
b.php

```
<?php
$name=$_REQUEST['$name'];
echo $name.'is updated';
?>
```

What is the mistake i am doing. And how can i fix this ?

Please help me.

Comment: Those one character mistakes that burn our brain cells out..

Comment: @Regent If you think that is the answer, make it an answer. The comments are not the place to answer questions.

Comment: i feel bad i did not noticed that

Comment: @winterblood oh, common, it's one-characher changing. It's just 30 seconds to figure out and not worth to be an answer. Moreover, as usually, someone else posts this as an answer in just several minutes.

Comment: @Mysteryos : That's true

Comment: @Regent: Thanks i updated, but i still can't able to get the values from b.php

Comment: @BIz well, is `alert("That box was checked.");` shown?

Comment: Now alert is shown, i forgot to add, <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>, And now i added, then the value that is passed by the checkbox is not showing

Comment: @Blz If you forgot about `#txt`, and about including jQuery, then you should have started your question description with mentioning that even `alert` is not showing. Incorrect question description is why answers are not fully helpful.

Comment: @BIz take a look at [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/z26pp8pk/) to see how it is supposed to be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
$name=$_REQUEST['$name'];
echo $name.'is updated';
?>
```

change this to

```
<?php
$name=$_REQUEST['name'];
echo $name.'is updated';
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is two mistake in your code:

First: You have passed wrong index value in $_REQUEST
try following:

```
<?php
    $name=$_REQUEST['name'];
    echo $name.'is updated';
?>
```

Second: You are trying to get value of element with id "#txt" which doesn't exist.
try following:

```
<script>
    cbChanged = function(checkboxElem) {
      if (checkboxElem.checked) {           
           $.post("b.php",
                 {name: "Hello"}).done(function(data){
                  $('#stage').html(data);
                   }
              );
        alert("That box was checked.");
      } else {
        alert("That box was unchecked.");
      }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: if you need to get value of "$_REQUEST['name']", you must have to pass value of name in your "$.post" request. And in current example you haven't this element that's why you get error of undefined index

Comment: thanks, i updated..But i am not getting the values from b.php file

Answer (score 0):

Since you commented that you corrected `$_REQUEST['name']` from `$_REQUEST['$name']`, and assuming you imported jquery already in your page, and that you have an input element (or an element with a value attribute) with `id='txt'`, <strike>all you need to do is put some quotes around the key name in your post methods second parameter (since you have a variable with that name already)</strike>, I suppose you should be just fine (@Regent, thanks for pointing out the key-value pair is technically valid, even if I don't like it. Though I'm not sure what the fiddle proves, as it's client side, and you're alerting the value of the variable prior to the post; but I tested again, and found I was wrong).

In the case that you are still unable to get a PHP reply, since I already answered anyway, this works just fine for me:

```
<!-- HTML + JS -->
<script src="../../js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<form id="myform">
    <input type="checkbox" name="check1" value="check1">
    <input type="checkbox" name="check2" value="check2">
    <input id="txt" value="test">
</form>
<div id="stage"></div>
<script>
    $('#myform [type=checkbox]').change(function(){
        $.post('b.php', {name:$('#txt').val()}, function(data){
            $('#stage').append(data + "<br/>");
        });
    });
</script>
```

b.php:

```
<?php
    $name = $_REQUEST["name"];
    echo $name." is updated";
?>
```

Comment: `{ 'name': name }` is the same to `{ name: name }`. Take a look at [mentioned fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/z26pp8pk/) to see that it works just fine.